# Passed your way - meaning

Tags: meaning

An excerpt from the lyrics for a song called "Mountains of Makkah" sung by Zain Bhikha

> Oh Mountains of Makkah, what can you say
>   Of the day that Ibrahim **passed your way**?
>   And He was instructed by God to build
>   A House of peace where people will pray

How do you understand **passed your way**?

Comment: Went near where you were. Think of it as "passed by your house"

Comment: Yes; it's probably unhelpful to think of 'passed your way' as the same sort of verb + direct object construction as 'passed your school'.

Comment: [Pass](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pass?q=pass).

Comment: I undestand the literal meaning: Ibrahim [passed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pass?q=pass) your [way](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/way?q=way) = Ibrahim "went across" your "path for travelling along".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *pass someone's way* means to pass nearby or in their vicinity. Here the author wants to ask mountains that what can they say of the day when Ibrahim passed nearby or in their vicinity. Maybe, Ibrahim passed their way as in his journey.

A [forum thread here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/178543-pass-someone-s-way) about the phrase.